# ModX Revolution Gallery get albaum list

Tags: modx-revolution

I've installed Gallery on ModX revo.

```
[[Gallery? &album=`My Album`]]
```

works quite ok - I get privew of all pics in albaum. But

```
[[GalleryAlbums? &limit=`10`]]
```

returns nothing. But why? I get 2 albaums in my gallery. Asked on ModX froum but no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, albaums must be set in "Prominent" status.